# Are lives and coins saved after restarting the console?

Tags: super-mario-land-2-6-golden-coins

In some Mario games, extra lives get reset after saving the game and reloading your file. (Mario 64, Galaxy, etc) In *Super Mario Land 2: 6 Golden Coins*, will my extra lives and coins be saved if I reset my console and reload my save file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing myself, extra lives, coins, and the enemies killed counter are preserved after resetting and loading a file. However, Mario's last power-up will be lost.